# How to plot conditional means per month over time in R for different brands

Tags: r

I am looking to plot data similar to this plot.

[image: this plot]

I have the following data. Dates in `DD/MM/YY` format .

````r
mydata$PUBLISH_DATE = as.Date(mydata$PUBLISH_DATE, format = "%d/%m/%y") ```
|Date         | Brand       |   Price   |
|-------------|-------------|-----------|
|01/01/2020   | Caltex      |   XXX     |
|01/01/2020   | Caltex      |   XXY     |
|    .        |             |           |
|    .        | Puma        |   XXT     |
|    .        |             |           |
|31/03/2021   |  BP         |   ABC     |
````

I am aiming to find the mean price of Caltex, Puma, BP, etc for each month from 01/20 to 03/21 and then plot them in a similar way to the image attached.

I have tried the manual way with no luck:

```r
mean(price[mydata$MONTH_Year=="01/20"][mydata$BRAND_DESCRIPTION=="Puma"]) #comes up with NA).
```

However this command yields a result:

```r
mean(price[mydata$MONTH_Year=="01/20"])
```

Is there anything I'm doing with the manual way that is wrong, or is there a more efficient way to plot everything at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
group_by(BRAND_DESCRIPTION, MONTH_Year) %>%
summarize(mean_price = mean(price)) #add na.rm = T if you have NAs
```

That should give you a dataframe with columns BRAND_DESCRIPTION, MONTH_Year and mean_price.

Comment: Thanks, when i tried that i got this message "Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"". Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Replace 'df' with the name of your dataframe